# Initialisation of CustomElement removes class methods(get/set also) if property with same name set before element defined

Tags: javascript, polymer, custom-element, lit-element

Custom-element could be initialised asynchronously, for instance after lazy loading its definition class.

Lets take a look at this example, we have an element sitting in the DOM that is not initialised yet:

```
<component-with-async-init></component-with-async-init>
```

Before initialisation we set a `value` property of this element:

```
querySelector('component-with-async-init').value = "GETTERS SETTERS ARE KILLED"
```

Then we init this element by defining it as a custom element. As you can see its definition class has getter and setter for `value` property.

```
class ComponentWithAsyncInit extends HTMLElement{
    static get is() {
        return 'component-with-async-init'
    }
    get value(){
        console.log("Getting value")
        return "VALUE FROM GETTER"
    }
    set value(v){
        console.log("Setting value")
    }
}

window.customElements.define(ComponentWithAsyncInit.is, ComponentWithAsyncInit);
```

Getters and setters(or any method) are now killed, as you can see:

```
querySelector('component-with-async-init').value //"GETTERS SETTERS ARE KILLED"
```

I observe this behaviour in latest Safari, Firefox and Chrome, others not tested. This problem affects Polymer and Lit-Element libraries as well as pure custom elements.
Seems like it works the same way in every browser.

**Question: Is it really an expected behaviour? Getters and Setters and any methods get wiped out if a property was set before element definition. If yes, what will be a workaround since we usually can't control when element value is set**

**Snippet:**

```js
document.querySelector('component-with-async-init').value = "SETTERS GETTERS KILLED"
document.querySelector('component-with-async-init').getSomeValue = "GET SOME VALUE KILLED"

class ComponentWithAsyncInit extends HTMLElement{
    static get is() {
        return 'component-with-async-init'
    }
    get value(){
        console.log("Getting value")
        return "VALUE FROM GETTER"
    }
    set value(v){
        console.log("Setting value")
    }

    getSomeValue(){
        return "SOME VALUE"
    }
}

window.customElements.define(ComponentWithAsyncInit.is, ComponentWithAsyncInit);
console.log("getSomeValue method:")
console.log(document.querySelector('component-with-async-init').getSomeValue)            
console.log("Reading value:")
console.log(document.querySelector('component-with-async-init').value)
```

```html
<component-with-async-init></component-with-async-init>
```

Comment: Why can't you ensure that the custom element definition runs before anything else that uses the element?

Comment: @Barmar This is how lazy loading pattern for custom elements should work in my understanding. Complex elements that have not been loaded resting in a DOM as empty divs without breaking application structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's indeed expected. The [HTML specs](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#html-element-constructors) ask that when a CustomElement is created UAs

> 12. Perform `element.[[SetPrototypeOf]](prototype)`.

Which is [the one from ECMAScript standards](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-ordinary-object-internal-methods-and-internal-slots-setprototypeof-v) and which only sets the `[[Prototype]]` from which `element` will inherit.
Doing this does not override own properties values.

```js
const elem = { a: "my own a" };
Object.setPrototypeOf(elem, { a: "proto's a", b: "proto's b" });
console.log(elem.a) // "my own a"
console.log(elem.b) // "proto's b"
```

You could try to workaround that by explicitly setting again the properties that have been overridden, and then set back the values so that the setters get called,

```js
document.querySelector('component-with-async-init').value = "SETTERS GETTERS KILLED";
document.querySelector('component-with-async-init').getSomeValue = "GET SOME VALUE KILLED";

class ComponentWithAsyncInit extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    // first grab the properties that might already have been set
    const ownProps = Object.entries(this);
    // our class's prototype
    const proto = ComponentWithAsyncInit.prototype;
    // get all properties descriptors
    const proto_desc = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(proto);

    ownProps.forEach(([key, value]) => {
      // got overriden
      if (key in proto_desc) {
        // apply the one from our class
        Object.defineProperty(this, key, proto_desc[key]);
        // set again the own property (call setters)
        this[key] = value;
      }
    });
  }
  static get is() {
    return 'component-with-async-init'
  }
  get value() {
    console.log("Getting value")
    return "VALUE FROM GETTER"
  }
  set value(v) {
    console.log("Setting value")
  }

  getSomeValue() {
    return "SOME VALUE"
  }
}

window.customElements.define(ComponentWithAsyncInit.is, ComponentWithAsyncInit);
customElements.upgrade(document.querySelector('component-with-async-init'))
console.log("getSomeValue method:")  // note that this will get overidden anyway
console.log(document.querySelector('component-with-async-init').getSomeValue)
console.log("Reading value:")
console.log(document.querySelector('component-with-async-init').value)
```

```html
<component-with-async-init></component-with-async-init>
```

But that sounds really ugly, and wouldn't prevent things like method calls before they get initialized.

So the best is probably to wait for your elements' registration before using these.

```js
customElements.whenDefined("component-with-async-init")
  .then(() => {
    document.querySelector('component-with-async-init').value = "SETTERS GETTERS KILLED"
    document.querySelector('component-with-async-init').getSomeValue = "GET SOME VALUE KILLED"
    console.log("getSomeValue method:") // note that this will get overidden anyway
    console.log(document.querySelector('component-with-async-init').getSomeValue)            
    console.log("Reading value:")
    console.log(document.querySelector('component-with-async-init').value)
  });
class ComponentWithAsyncInit extends HTMLElement{
    static get is() {
        return 'component-with-async-init'
    }
    get value(){
        console.log("Getting value")
        return "VALUE FROM GETTER"
    }
    set value(v){
        console.log("Setting value")
    }

    getSomeValue(){
        return "SOME VALUE"
    }
}

window.customElements.define(ComponentWithAsyncInit.is, ComponentWithAsyncInit);
```

```html
<component-with-async-init></component-with-async-init>
```